# Identify the text following a specific string with Selenium IE webdriver and JAVA

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I identify whether the text following "FIND ME PLEASE" is "YES" or "NO"? (i.e. "FIND ME PLEASE 1" is followed by "YES". "FIND ME PLEASE 2" is followed by "NO"). Please refer to the HTML below:

```
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="1">
<tr><td width="100" align="right">&nbsp;1.&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td width="400" class="fontlarge">&nbsp;&nbsp;`Is <b>FIND ME PLEASE 1</b> OK ?</td>
<td width="100" class="textbold" align="center">YES</td>
<table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="1">
<tr><td width="100" align="right">&nbsp;2.&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td width="400" class="fontlarge">&nbsp;&nbsp;Is <b>FIND ME PLEASE 2</b> OK ?</td>
<td width="100" class="textbold" align="center">NO</td>
```

I managed to identify `"FIND ME PLEASE [1 or 2]"` using xpath; i.e. By:

```
xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + "FIND ME PLEASE " + "')]")
```

I have a feeling I need to use `"following-sibling"` to identify the `"YES"` or `"NO"`, but not sure how to use it correctly.

Comment: The xpath code posted is thanks to @Slanec from another question I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is a bit unclear to me in your question, but I think you look for something like :

```
//td[contains(.,'FIND ME PLEASE')][./following-sibling::td[contains(.,'YES')]]
```

That will give you all the `td` containing `FIND ME PLEASE` with a following sibling `td` containing `YES`.

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath. Should work. Please let me know if you want any clarificaitons

//tr[td/b[text() = 'FIND ME PLEASE 1']]/descendant::td[@class = 'textbold']

Comment: This also worked! This directly allows me to identify whether it's a "YES" or "NO" following the text. Thanks for the help.